# How to draw splatter (one color) on 2D grid to cover approximate number of pixels? (looking for algorithm/math answers)

Tags: mathematics, textures, algorithm

Imagine a 2D grid, where water stain increasing because of water drops. But not in plain circular way but more like noisy-splatter way. Or like corruption way. I want to create effect that will increase existing splatter (if drop of water drops into position where splatter exists) or will create new (if drop of water drops into position where pixel is clear).

And it would be nice if I would be available to create approximate percentage coverage.

What algorithms should I use for this? What formulas?

I tried to sketch example: [image]

Comment: Can you share a picture demonstrating the kind of appearance you want? It could be a sample from an existing game, a hand drawn diagram, or any other source that will help readers get on the same page as you.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for the comment! I tried to add sketch of what I was explaining. It is kinda difficult to show what I mean by percentage though... But basically I want to create noise or something based splatter AND contain the growth of it in some kind of "image coverage percentage". Basically game will have success points based on users proper percentage coverage of area with drops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to loop over the pixels in your image (or process them in parallel with a shader). For each pixel, measure its distance to the center of each splat, and subtract the radius of the splat. This gives you a signed distance field (SDF): negative values are inside the splat, positive values are outside. Take the minimum of this SDF over all splats, and colour the pixels with negative values black and positive values white. (You can also use intermediate greys for values close to zero for a smooth antialiased effect)

Out of the box, that just gives you simple circular splats. But we can make them look more blobby and organic by adding a little noise. For each pixel you can generate a noise value using something like Perlin noise, or sampling from a texture with some random fuzzy shapes. Add a multiple of that noise value to your SDF value to bias it slightly - making some pixels that are strictly outside the radius count as inside, and some pixels that are strictly inside the radius count as outside. This breaks up the simple circular border and makes it look a little more naturalistic. Using different noise functions/textures and different multipliers can help you art direct the particular shape of the border.

Here's an example of this as a Unity shader that will draw up to four splats in one pass:

[image: Splats growing and moving]

```
Shader "Unlit/Splats"
{
    Properties
    {
        _SplatPos1("Splat Positions A/B", Vector) = (1, 2, 10, 10)
        _SplatPos2("Splat Positions C/D", Vector) = (5, 7, 20, 5)
        _Intensity("Splat Intensity A/B/C/D", Vector) = (10, 5, 1, 0)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            float4 _SplatPos1;
            float4 _SplatPos2;

            float4 _Intensity;

            // Perlin noise implementation by Inigo Quilez,
            // via https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/gradientnoise/gradientnoise.htm
            float2 hash(float2 p) {
                const float2 k = float2(0.3183099f, 0.3678794f);
                p = p * k + k.yx;
                return -1.0f + 2.0f * frac(16.0f * k * frac(p.x * p.y * (p.x + p.y)));
            }

            float3 noised(float2 p) {
                float2 corner = floor(p);
                float2 t = p - corner;

                float2 u = t * t * t * (t * (t * 6.0f - 15.0f) + 10.0f);
                float2 du = 30.0f * t * t * (t * (t - 2.0f) + 1.0f);

                float2 ga = hash(corner + float2(0, 0));
                float2 gb = hash(corner + float2(1, 0));
                float2 gc = hash(corner + float2(0, 1));
                float2 gd = hash(corner + float2(1, 1));

                float va = dot(ga, t - float2(0, 0));
                float vb = dot(gb, t - float2(1, 0));
                float vc = dot(gc, t - float2(0, 1));
                float vd = dot(gd, t - float2(1, 1));

                return float3(va + u.x * (vb - va) + u.y * (vc - va) + u.x * u.y * (va - vb - vc + vd),
                    ga + u.x * (gb - ga) + u.y * (gc - ga) + u.x * u.y * (ga - gb - gc + gd) +
                    du * (u.yx * (va - vb - vc + vd) + float2(vb, vc) - va));
            }


            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            float splat(float noise, float2 offset, float intensity) {
                return intensity - length(offset) + noise * saturate(intensity/2.0f) * 1.5f;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                const float scale = 30.0f;

                float2 p = i.uv * scale;
                float noise = noised(p).x + noised(p).x;                

                float intensity = max(
                    max(
                        splat(noise, i.uv * scale - _SplatPos1.xy, _Intensity.x),
                        splat(noise, i.uv * scale - _SplatPos1.zw, _Intensity.y)
                    ), 
                    max(
                        splat(noise, i.uv * scale - _SplatPos2.xy, _Intensity.z),
                        splat(noise, i.uv * scale - _SplatPos2.zw, _Intensity.w)
                    )
                );

                float speed = fwidth(intensity);

                float distance = intensity / speed;

                return smoothstep(0, 1, 1.0f - (distance + 0.5f));
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```